# Copy data from workbook to another workbook matching columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master data file (Conso.xls) where I consolidate information from several countries (Country1, 2, 3.xls). Both Conso and Country have the same rows, which are expense concepts, they are in A4:A32. The column headers, that are weeks (e.g. W31, W32, w33) are in different positions or cells depending on the country but always on the 2nd row. For example, in one Excel file W31 will be in A2 and in another in D2 (always 2nd row, but different column).

I am trying to make a macro that looks for the column header in the country book and copies the data below it to the Conso book, to the column with the same header (W31, w32, w33) etc.  It would be nice to have a msgbox that pops up and asks to which specific sheet within the workbook to copy the data to.

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range, c As Range, msg As String
With Sheets("Backend - raw").Range("4:4").CurrentRegion
    For Each r In Sheets("Backend - processed").Range("b7:t7")
        Set c = .Rows(1).Find(r.Value, , , xlWhole, , 0)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            .Columns(c.Column).Copy
            r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            msg = msg & vbLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: could you not use formulas to show the data in your destination sheet?

Comment: You could use an Inputbox.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies. @OurManinBananas SJRI would rather not use formulas as the sheet gets pretty heavy with all the references and also there is the inefficiency of changing them every time. Regarding the input box i know how they work and would be able to but sometimes struggle to get them in the code properly.